# Make parent container take flex items width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list container with limited height. It has list of some child items. These items should be placed from top to bottom and from left to right. If there are more and more elements, they'll be placed in a new column on the right.

[image]

How can I make the parent container take the width from the content? So that the parent container doesn't expand to the full width of the window and hide the next columns?

**What I tried:**
I tried to set different display of the parents, but the children from the second column get hidden, and the entire width of the `.parent_item` = the width of the first column only.

**Example:**

```css
.parent {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 80vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 2px;
}

.parent_item {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  gap: 2px;
  max-width: max-content;
  overflow: auto;
}

.parent_item div {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent_item">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent_item">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Perhaps add some illustrations of what you have and what you want.

Comment: Should there be a div class="parent" somewhere in your html?

Comment: Sorry, added div class=parent

Comment: Added screenshot of desired layout behavior

Answer (score 1):

By using [display contents](https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents#:%7E:text=display%3A%20contents%20causes%20an%20element%27s,grid%20or%20similar%20layout%20techniques.) you can make display flex ignore its children and make it flex the grand children, check the snippet for the result.

```css
.parent {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 80vw;
  gap: 3px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grand-child {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
}

.child {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">1</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">3</div>
    <div class="grand-child">4</div>
    <div class="grand-child">5</div>
    <div class="grand-child">6</div>
    <div class="grand-child">7</div>
    <div class="grand-child">8</div>
    <div class="grand-child">9</div>
    <div class="grand-child">10</div>
    <div class="grand-child">11</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">1</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">3</div>
    <div class="grand-child">4</div>
    <div class="grand-child">5</div>
    <div class="grand-child">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To make the row cells start in a new row for another child use the following CSS styling;

```css
.parent {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 80vw;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  margin: 2px;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 3px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grand-child {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">1</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">3</div>
    <div class="grand-child">4</div>
    <div class="grand-child">5</div>
    <div class="grand-child">6</div>
    <div class="grand-child">7</div>
    <div class="grand-child">8</div>
    <div class="grand-child">9</div>
    <div class="grand-child">10</div>
    <div class="grand-child">11</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">1</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">3</div>
    <div class="grand-child">4</div>
    <div class="grand-child">5</div>
    <div class="grand-child">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this solved your issue, if it didn't let me know, and I will look into it some more.

Comment: Thanks, but my tasks can have a few `.parent_item` and each new item will start on a new column. p.s. Edited the picture for better clarity

Comment: Does this solve your issue? I've edited the post

Comment: I've included two different approaches, the first approach basically ignores the child elements, the second method makes the children have seperate cells

Comment: The second option is very good! It is working. But there are nuances: the width of the grand-child is not equal to the width of their content. All cells fill the max-width of the parent, which also has a fill width. Ideally, the parent container should take the width of the child content and nothing else. What if we replace max-width:80vw to max-width:fit-content, we will see this situation: the parent container doesn't have the full width, but hides the second columns.